# std::shared_ptr for value in std::map destroying my object

Tags: c++, dictionary, shared-ptr

I had a problem with some of my code with the following function calls:

```
User::User(const Socket::SocketAddress& addr) {
    address = addr;
    _usersListBySession.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<User>>(sessionID, std::shared_ptr<User>(this)));
    assert(this->address == addr); // succeeds
    _userListByAddress.insert(std::pair<Socket::SocketAddress, std::shared_ptr<User>>(addr, std::shared_ptr<User>(this)));
    assert(this->address == addr); // fails
}
```

I fixed the issue by doing this:

```
User::User(const Socket::SocketAddress& addr) {
    address = addr;
    std::shared_ptr<User> user(this);
    _usersListBySession.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<User>>(sessionID, user));
    assert(this->address == addr); // succeeds
    _userListByAddress.insert(std::pair<Socket::SocketAddress, std::shared_ptr<User>>(addr, user));
    assert(this->address == addr); // succeeds
}
```

What did I do and why does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, you assign `this` to two different `std::shared_ptr`s, resulting in a double `delete`.

In your second example, you assign `this` to *one* `std::shared_ptr user`, which gets ref-counted properly, when you give it as a parameter to insert.

Comment: So as a rule of thumb, you shouldn't assign a single object to multiple shared pointers.

Comment: @user1843978 Correct, because then every shared pointer takes ownership and wants to delete this single object, when its reference count drops to zero.